# unknown operator: "$or" in mgo

Tags: go, mgo

I'm getting `unknown operator: $or` error with code below and couldn't figure out why.

```
vc := &storers.VCategory{}

err = mndb.
    C("virtualcategoryprototypes").
    Find(bson.M{
        "children":   nil,
        "deleted_by": nil,
        "indexCycleNo": bson.M{"$or": []bson.M{
            bson.M{"$exists": false},
            bson.M{"$lt": cycle}}}}).
    One(vc)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `$or` expression is a series (array) of other conditions which are valid on their own (and which will be evaluated using logical OR connection), and the result of the `$or` expression will be in logical AND connection with other conditions at the same level.

So you have to move the `$or` operator up one level, its value must be a slice or array, and the elements of `$or` will be in your case `indexCycleNo: {$exists: false}` and `indexCycleNo: {$lt: cycle}`:

```
err = mndb.
    C("virtualcategoryprototypes").
    Find(bson.M{
        "children":   nil,
        "deleted_by": nil,
        "$or": []bson.M{
            {"indexCycleNo": bson.M{"$exists": false}},
            {"indexCycleNo": bson.M{"$lt": cycle}},
        },
    }).
    One(vc)
```

Comment: Such a simple error and I'm here trying to figure out for more than 3 hours. Thank you very much.